# vuetifyjs.js carousels не могу подключить картинки из текущей папки. не видит картинки. Хотя через тег <v-img> все картинки выводит

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vue.js, vuetify

```
     <template>
       <v-carousel hide-delimiters>
         <v-carousel-item
         v-for="(item,i) in items"
         :key="i"
         :src="item.src"
         ></v-carousel-item>
       </v-carousel>
    </template>
   <script>
   export default {
      data () {
        return {
         items: [
        {
               src: '@/assets/img1.jpg',
         },
       {
              src: '@/assets/img2.jpg',
       },

      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: а точно .gpg а не .jpg ?)

Comment: Это я опечатался, Вы правы jpg

Comment: но проблема всё-равно не решилась?

Comment: Нет, конечно. Не в этом беда..... Трабл  в том, что картинки не успевают подгружаться.